# Does QSaveFile::commit() fsync() the file to the filesystem?

Tags: linux, qt, synchronization, atomic, fsync

QSaveFile is recommended for atomic writes to the filesystem.
How does it work?

Does QSaveFile::commit() fsync() the file to the filesystem?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and no.

It writes to a temporary file, fsync()-it, and then renames it to the desired filename.
But the rename is not fsync()-ed. So in case of a power loss, the new file will not take place until the OS decides to write.

My solution is to call this after commit(): (linux only)

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

saveFile.write(saveDoc.toJson());
saveFile.commit();

QFileInfo fi(saveFile.fileName());
int fd = ::open(fi.absolutePath().toLocal8Bit().data(), O_RDONLY);
::fsync(fd);
::close(fd);
```

Comment: `fsync` doesn't flush the directory metadata, only the file's own inode (and its data).   Renaming a file within the same filesystem only updates the change-time in the inode, which is a pretty minor detail to worry about syncing.  The inode number stays the same, so if a directory entry referring to it makes it to disk (and the fsync finished before crash or power loss), you'll get consistent file data and metadata, with either the original `ctime` from `fsync(fd)`, or milliseconds later after `rename()`.

Comment: As the [Linux fsync man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fdatasync.2.html#DESCRIPTION) says, *Calling  fsync()  does not necessarily ensure that the entry in the directory containing the file has also reached disk.  **For that an explicit fsync() on a file   descriptor for the directory is also needed.***  You may have the directory open anyway if you're using `openat` and so on relative to that directory fd, otherwise you'd need to open it with O_DIRECTORY.